# How to create an windows/phone application from a website like a Discord?

Tags: windows, web, discord, client

Alternative title: **How does discord work?**

While I was making my website, I noticed it looks more like an application that could be downloadable. So I thought, what if I do exactly that? However, I have no idea how.

For example, take something like a discord. This is (I at least think) a Web integrated into a client application.

So is there a way to take my website, and not as easy as possible make a windows application from it? And how does the discord client work (the PC one)?

EDIT: My website uses php

Comment: Verify simplified explanation: [Multitier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)

Answer (score -1):

So yes, I found an answer if anyone ever asks the same question as me.

It is done via the Electron framework. I don't understand it that much to talk about it more.

So the answer is: **Electron framework**